# Unable to edit href parameter of Tweet button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I'm writing random quote app which has to show random quote along with author and then edit *href* parameter of Tweet button, but I can't manage to get it, I tried with jQuery's .attr() function on both, #b (id of the button) but still nothing happens. This is plain example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var quotes = {"Steve Jobs": "Things don't have to change the world to be important.",
          "Sigmund Freud":" If youth knew; if age could.",
          "Albert Einstein": "You can't blame gravity for falling in love.",
          "Amelia Earhart": "Women, like men, should try to do the impossible. And when they fail, their failure should be challenge to others.",
          "Mahatma Gandhi": "Where there is a love, there is a life.",
          "Buddha": "Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentra the mind on present moment.",
          "Buddha": "The mind is everything. What you think you become.",
          "Winston Churchill": "Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm.",
          "Audrey Hepburn": "Nothing is impossible, the word itself says 'I'm possible'!",
          "Milton Berle": "If opportunity doesn't knock, build a door.",
          "Swami Sivananda": "Put your heart, mind, and soul into even your smallest acts. This is the secret of success.",
          "John F. Kenedy": "Mankind must put an end to war before war puts an end to mankind.",
          "Hugh Hefner": "Surrounding myself with beautiful women keeps me young.",
          "Mahatma Gandhi": "It is health that is real wealth and not pieces of gold and silver."
          }

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var author = [];
  var quote = [];
  var tweetText = "";

  for (var a in quotes) {
    author.push(a);
    quote.push(quotes[a]);
  }

  var randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, 13);
  $("#quote-content").text(quote[randomNumber]);
  $("#quote-author").text(author[randomNumber]);

  $("#generator").click(function(){
      randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, 13);
      $("#quote-content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#quote-content").text(quote[randomNumber]);
      });
    
      $("#quote-author").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#quote-author").text(author[randomNumber]);
      });
    
      $("#quote-content").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#quote-author").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});

window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 
  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };
 
  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: #000000; }

cite, footer {
  color: #ecf0f1; }

#quote {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 15pt;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px; }

blockquote {
  border-left: none; }

blockquote:before {
  content: "\f10d";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 20pt;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px; }

#generator {
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  margin-left: 5px; }

#generator:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2ecc71; }

.twitter {
  float: right; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='panel panel-default' id='quote'>
    <blockquote>
      <div id='quote-content'>
        This is random quote
      </div>
      <footer>
        <cite id='quote-author' title='author'>
          Source
        </cite>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
    <a class='btn btn-default' id='generator'>
      Get another quote
    </a>
    <div class='twitter'>
      <a class='twitter-share-button btn btn-default' data-size='large' href='' id='tweet-button'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the expected behavior. Particularly the meaning of: "but I can't manage to get it". To get what? I see two buttons: "Get another quote" and "Tweet". It looks like the prior changes the quote being displayed. But I'm not sure what's broken. Perhaps clicking the Get Another Quote button is also supposed to update the `href` of the Twitter button? It would be helpful to hear exactly what you're looking for. Be it in the feature's behavior (I click this, this should happen) or in the code's behavior (I click this, the href should change to this). Hope that helps.

Comment: @TCannadySF https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button
When I click on Get another quote, app has to change href parameter of tweet button with text parameter in url as quote text + quote author and open new pop-up to share the quote. I cannot do that, whenever I try I just get URL of current page, but not a text. Only when I define URL manually on #tweet-button element, it works, but I need it to work always.